# Blobs filled with black color

Tags: iphone, image, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

After filling the interested blobs I am getting the output image as below (0,9,8..etc are filled with black color). How can I rectify this? I used the function FillBlob() of cvBlobLib for blob filling. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.[image: Output Image]

Comment: I don't really understand, what is being asked here. What is the connection between filling blobs and rectification?

Comment: Maybe show the original image as well so we understand why you use FillBlob in the first place if you don't want the holes to be filled…

Answer (score 0):

Maybe providing details on the following questions will enable others to answer you questions in a better manner:

1. What problem are you trying to solve?
2. The original image/sample code
3. You mentioned that you used cvBlobLib;Any specific parameters that you used to achieve the end solution?
4. Any other approaches that you had previously tried on the same image, but didnt work?

Comment: what are you answering, seems like a comment?